# Maximum and Supremum

Tags: maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

Please, I want to know

$\max_{x \in \{0,\frac{3}{4},1\}} (x-1/2)^2$, $\max_{x \in [0,1)} \min\{x,1/2\}$ and their $\arg \max$.

Thanks!

Comment: What is arg max?

Comment: The argument of the maximum

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know what “max” means?

Comment: Yes. I was used to the maximum of a set, not of a fonction on a set .

Comment: For the first one, $x$ can only be three values. Substitute each into $(x-1/2)^2$ and see what the largest value you get is. That’s the max. The value(s) of $x$ that give you that max is(are) the argmax.

Comment: For the second one, $x$ can be any value in $[0,1)$. Try substituting several values from that half open interval into $\min\{x, 1/2\}$ to see what you get, and try to reason about what the maximum value you can get is, and which values of $x$ will give you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part

$max_{x\in\{0,\frac34, 1\}}(x-\frac12)^2$=$max\{\frac14, \frac1{16}, \frac14\}$=$\frac 14$ and the argmax are $0,1$.

Note you could have easily predicted the max and the argmax by observing that the function to be maximised represents a parabola with vertex at $(\frac 12,0) $ with axis parallel to $y-axis$(since the parabolic function is decreasing on left and increasing on right of vertex)

Now for the second part

Take $A=[0,\frac12]$ and $B=(\frac 12,1)$

Then for $x \in A$ , $min\{x,\frac12\}=x$ and for $x\in B$, $\min \{x,\frac12\}=\frac12$

So $max_{x\in[0,1)}min\{x,\frac12\}=max\{\min_{x\in A}\{x,\frac12\}\cup min_{x\in B}\{x,\frac12\}\}$

$=max\{A\cup\{\frac12\}\}=\frac12$

Clearly the argmax is $B\cup \{\frac12\}=[\frac12,1)$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay. Thanks! But I didn't understand why you wrote $\max \{A \cup \{\frac{1}{2}\}\}$ because you set above that for $X \in A, \min\{x,\frac{1}{2}\}=x....,$ then, where did you find again A?

Comment: As $x$ varies over $A$ , $min\{x,\frac12\}=x $ and that's why $min_{x\in A}\{x,\frac12\}=A$. In simple words , every point of $A$ is achieved by the minimum function on varying the points over $A$